# SELECT clause using exists with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables : Sneed , applies, coursepass

```
//Sneed 
P#         SNAME
------------------
0001         C
0002         C++
0003         JAVA
0004         C

//Applies
A#          P#
----------------
000001      0001
000002      0002
000003      0001

//coursepass
A#        TITLE
---------------------
000001    C PROGRAM
000002    JAVA
000003    PRINTING
```

my question is to find the title of coursepass by the applicants who applied for the position need a skill(Sneed) name 'C'

I used the following query

```
SELECT cp.CTITLE FROM COURSEPASSED cp WHERE
EXISTS 
(SELECT P# FROM APPLIES ap WHERE cp.A#=ap.A# AND
EXISTS
(SELECT P# FROM SNEEDED sn WHERE sname='C programming'));
```

but get an empty result.
my output should be like this

```
TITLE
---------
C PROGRAM  //  <--- As P#=0001 required 'C'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your clauses is this:

```
EXISTS (SELECT P# FROM SNEEDED sn WHERE sname='C programming');
```

This returns `FALSE` because `sname` never takes on the value `'C programming'`.  Hence the entire clause returns `FALSE`.

For your sample data, you would use:

```
EXISTS (SELECT P# FROM SNEEDED sn WHERE sname = 'C');
```

Perhaps you mean:

```
EXISTS (SELECT P# FROM SNEEDED sn WHERE sname = 'C' or sname like 'C %');
```

EDIT:

The logic for your query doesn't look right.  Your overall query should probably have explicit joins to combine these readily combinable tables:

```
SELECT cp.CTITLE
FROM COURSEPASSED cp JOIN
     APPLIES a
     ON cp.A# = a.A# JOIN
     SNEEDED s
     ON s.P# = a.P# 
WHERE sname = 'C';
```

Comment: but seem like i only able to use nested queries. which mean need multiple select and can use exists / not exists clause only. thats why i thinking the logic for that...

Comment: @MatBailie . . . The edit does not make that assumption.  Although there could be exact duplicates in `APPLIES`, that is unlikely.  But `APPLIES` does have one-to-many relationships with each of the other tables.  The reason this doesn't matter (in terms of duplicates) is because of the `where` clause.

Comment: @user3553846 . . . There is the "right" way to write the query using explicit joins, especially for three tables related like this (a very common situation).  You can use `exists`, but you will still need `join`s in the subqueries, unless you want a real abomination of a query.